# Change CSS when id is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the CSS class of class="Name1" when id"section-2" is reached.and also change CSS of class="Name2"  if id "section-3" is reached.

This code only works for one section.

**CSS**

```
.Name1 {
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
.Name2 {
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
.rotate {
     -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
     transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    $('.Name1').toggleClass('rotate',
        scroll >= $('#section-2').offset().top
    ); 
}); 
$(window).scroll();
```

**HTML**

```
<ol class="curtains"> 
  <li id="section-1" class="cover" ">
    <section class="center-block">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="col1-1 centered">

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li> 
  <li id="section-2" class="cover" style="background-color:#e74c3c">
    <section class="center-block">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="col1-2"> 
            <h4 class="Name1">Name1</h4>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </section>
  </li> 
  <li id="section-3" class="cover" style="background-color:#16a085">
    <section class="center-block">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix">  
        <div class="col1-2"> 
            <h4 class="Name2">Name 2</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
</ol>
```

and if i want to test to both 2 sections it doesn't work with this code.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    $('.Name1').toggleClass('rotate', 
        scroll >= $('#section-2').offset().top
    ); 
    $('.Name2').toggleClass('rotate', 
        scroll >= $('#section-3').offset().top
    ); 
}); 
$(window).scroll();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "reached"?

Comment: when arriving to id="Name2" during scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to have the rotation effect occur **when titles enter the viewport** from the bottom of the page.

This is what I understand by *«when arriving to id="Name2" during scrolling»*

I used `.addClass` and `.removeClass` and conditions based on the document scrolling **minus** the viewport height.

Because when using `.toggleClass` directly in the scroll event...
It toggles the class on/off something like 10 times on a pretty small mouse wheel rotation... And cause the animation to be weird or not working at all.

It also prevent the animation from occuring all the time when reading.

```
    //$(document).on("scroll", function(){console.log("document scroll!");});
    var viewportHeight = $(window).width();

    console.log("viewportHeight: "+viewportHeight);
    console.log("section-2 offset: "+$('#section-2').offset().top);
    console.log("section-3 offset: "+$('#section-3').offset().top);

    $(document).on("scroll",function(){
        var scrollVal = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        // Will rotate when window scroll offset is between section-2 and section-3 (both values minus viewport height)
        if((scrollVal >= $('#section-2').offset().top-viewportHeight) && (scrollVal < $('#section-3').offset().top-viewportHeight)){
            $('.Name1').addClass('rotate');
            console.log("Section 2 entered viewport!");
        }else{
            $('.Name1').removeClass('rotate');
        }

        // Will rotate when document scroll offset is greater than section-3 (value minus viewport height)
        if(scrollVal >= $('#section-3').offset().top-viewportHeight){
            $('.Name2').addClass('rotate');
            console.log("Section 3 entered viewport!");
        }else{
            $('.Name2').removeClass('rotate');
        }
    });
```

I also made minimal change to your CSS:

```
.Name1 {
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    width:10%;                          /* added */
}
.Name2 {
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    width:10%;                          /* added */
}
.rotate {
     transform-origin: center;          /* added */
     -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
     transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

See it in action in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/wmgk1bzw/)

Comment: I just completly changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to refer the element and instead of the `id` search for the parent, check this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('h4').each(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('rotate',
      scroll >= $(this).parents('.cover').offset().top
    );
  })
});
$(window).scroll();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.cover {
  height: 500px;
}
h4 {
  transform-origin: center;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 4em;
}
.Name1 {
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
.Name2 {
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
.rotate {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="curtains">
  <li id="section-1" class="cover">
    <section class="center-block ">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix ">
        <div class="col1-1 centered ">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
  <li id="section-2" class="cover" style="background-color:#e74c3c ">
    <section class="center-block ">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix ">
        <div class="col1-2 ">
          <h4 class="Name1 ">Name1</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
  <li id="section-3 " class="cover" style="background-color:#16a085 ">
    <section class="center-block ">
      <div class="wrapper clearfix ">
        <div class="col1-2 ">
          <h4 class="Name2 ">Name 2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
</ol>
```